# How to change default programming language in EA version 16.1?

Tags: enterprise-architect

there is already a post to this topic, but it refers to an older version: [How to change default programming language?](https://sparxsystems.com/forums/smf/index.php/topic,38708.msg240232.html#msg240232)
I cann´t find the menu for setting the default language with the help of that post.
Please let me know where I can find it.
I tried to find it with the search function (find command) in the top of EA "default programming language"

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the old version 13 and the current version 16 is the name of the ribbon. **Configure** in v13 is **Settings** in v16

The setting is found here:
**Settings | Model | Options | Source Code Engineering | Default Language for Code Generation**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After a long period of experimentation :-( I think I have found what I was looking for.
EA version 16.1 Settings.Model.Options.Source Code Engineering.Default Language for Coe Generation
[image]
in the dialog choose Source Code Engineering.Default Language
[image]

Comment: I think I posted exactly the same about 20 minutes prior to this answer.